# Why my background image doesn't appear when I put the url link in it? And how can I fix my buttons(they mustn't follow the navbar)?

Tags: css

Here is my problem code and advice me something fot the portfolio pls https://codepen.com/LukaBarliani/pen/xrGyRy

Comment: I couldnt add the correct link. It is this https://codepen.io/LukaBarliani/pen/xrGyRy

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the question here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Run your CSS through any CSS Linter and you will know why.

http://csslint.net/

Your CSS works fine after fixing some issues and ran through a CSS beautifier.

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
body {
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.button1 {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.button2 {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.button3 {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.intro-message {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}
.intro-header {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('https://40.media.tumblr.com/1b916597d3e174399cb7adadddb66ede/tumblr_nt5uk4psl31ud7rr3o1_1280.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 855px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```